# angular js routeprovider doenst work with angularjs and jqueryjs integrated

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a application which uses angular js and jquery js(Mobile and web). Im facing a problem where in which the route-provider doesn't rote to the concerned page if i use both jquery and angular js integrated.

If i remove one of jquery js files, the router works fine but the page css style disappears.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MAMALDBMMjVSUHGLTV4P?p=preview

Depicts the problem I am facing.

Any help on the same is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't work with jquery Mobile due to the routing issues, however there is a project that is in beta that might help.

https://github.com/angular-widgets/angular-jqm

Comment: Or have a look here: http://simonguest.com/2013/04/08/jquery-mobile-and-angularjs-working-together/